# Function return

Tags: php, function, navigationbar

I try make navigation bar.

```
/* Only for admin */
function getAccessRights($links) {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['right']) && $_SESSION['right'] === ACCESS_ADMIN  ||
        isset($_COOKIE['right']) && $_COOKIE['right'] === ACCESS_ADMIN ) {
        $links[] = '<li><a href="messages.phtml">Read messages</a></li>';
        var_dump($links); // **Back, Login, Read messages.**
        return $links;
    }
}



 function drawNavBar() {
    if ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/form-msg.php" ) {
        $links[] = '<li><a class="back" href="index.php">Back</a></li>';
        $links[] = '<li><a href="admin.php">Login</a></li>';
        getAccessRights(); // I dont know what access have user. If he have admin access, he will see link "read messages".
        var_dump($links) // **Back, Login**
    }
    //some if
    makeNavBar($links); //makeNavBar it is function which do pattern for html
  }
```

Where link "Read messages"? Maybe you know a better way to do make navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `drawNavBar`

```
$links[] = getAccessRights();
```

And in function `getAccessRights`

```
$links = array();
$links[] = '<li><a href="messages.phtml">Read messages</a></li>';
return $links;
```

By the way..the naming of the function `getAccessRights` is not right and I would try 
to use a more generic approach to the rights management for example a [Access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
//returns true or false based on user rights
function isAdmin() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['right']) && $_SESSION['right'] === ACCESS_ADMIN  || isset($_COOKIE['right']) && $_COOKIE['right'] === ACCESS_ADMIN)
}

 function drawNavBar($links = array()) {
    if ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/form-msg.php" ) {
        $links[] = '<li><a class="back" href="index.php">Back</a></li>';
        $links[] = '<li><a href="admin.php">Login</a></li>';
        if(isAdmin())
            $links[] = '<li><a href="messages.phtml">Read messages</a></li>';

        var_dump($links) // **Back, Login**
    }
    //some if
    makeNavBar($links);
  }
```

Comment: But if i will have many links, i must write this code for each page? I say about 'if(isAdmin())'.

Comment: Yes, you could also create a separate file, and just include that one in every file where you want this navigation bar to show up.
But as per note from `helmbert`, it is insecure to authorize an user based on a value in a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The link is the return value of the `getAccessRights()` method, but you call this method ignoring the return value. Furthermore, `getAccessRights()` expects a parameter `$links`, but you do not pass one.

BTW: You determine a user's admin status by a flag in the `$_COOKIE` variable. This is **highly insecure**. The `$_COOKIE`variable contains everything that is sent in the client's cookie. This means that the user can modify the cookie's contents (and make himself admin by editing his own cookie).